# Discord.py bot that can fetch from the Literature clock?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've been working on a slash command for my Discord bot that fetches the current text on the [Literature Clock website](https://literature-clock.jenevoldsen.com/) and outputs it in response to the slash command. I've tried using BeautifulSoup but the content on the page is dynamically loaded with javascript. So I tried using Selenium, but it still does not work. I was able to get the bot to respond, but all the fields such as "Quote:" "Author:" and "Book:" were empty.

Currently I have this code, which raises a `TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'`.

Looking for advice and help on making this work, or finding alternatives.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

@client.tree.command(name="literature-clock", description="Get a book quote for the current time.")
async def literature_clock(ctx):

    firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
    firefox_options.add_argument("--headless") 
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\shadowshard\OneDrive\Documents\geckodriver.exe", options=firefox_options)

    try:
        driver.get("https://literature-clock.jenevoldsen.com/")
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
        quote_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "lit_quote")
        quote_text = quote_element.text
        time_element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "em")
        time = time_element.text
        book_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "book")
        book = book_element.text
        author_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "author")
        author = author_element.text
        
        response_text = f"Quote: {quote_text}\nTime: {time}\nBook: {book}\nAuthor: {author}"
    except Exception as e:
        response_text = f"Error: {str(e)}"
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    await ctx.response.send_message(response_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest selenium version
simply use

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
```

instead of

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\shadowshard\OneDrive\Documents\geckodriver.exe", options=firefox_options)
```

You can see some examples [here](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

Also should add `defer` for time consuming tasks:

```
@client.tree.command(name="literature-clock", description="Get a book quote for the current time.")
async def literature_clock(ctx:discord.Interaction):
    await ctx.response.defer()
    # Your code
    await ctx.followup.send(response_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where we more or less just act as our own client, copying the js. I'm wondering what you tried?

Using Selenium for anything but tests is kinda icky, if you ask me.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def get_lit_quote(sfw=True):
    current_time = datetime.now()

    # Format the time to match the filename format based on lines 35+36 of view-source:https://literature-clock.jenevoldsen.com/.
    file_name = f"{current_time.hour:02d}_{current_time.minute:02d}.json"
    url = f"https://literature-clock.jenevoldsen.com/times/{file_name}"

    # Make the request - We're mostly just copying the javascript.
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return None

    lit_json = response.json()

    # Filter for sfw if required - copying line 19 context.
    if sfw:
        lit_json = [item for item in lit_json if item.get('sfw') == 'yes']

    if not lit_json:
        return None

    # select a quote yourself
    lit_json_single = lit_json[0]  

    # Extract quote details
    quote_first = lit_json_single['quote_first']
    quote_time_case = lit_json_single['quote_time_case']
    quote_last = lit_json_single['quote_last']
    title = lit_json_single['title']
    author = lit_json_single['author']

    # Ex. - Do whatever *you* need with this dict, or change the output format.
    return {
        "quote": f"{quote_first} {quote_time_case} {quote_last}",
        "book": title,
        "author": author
    }

quote_data = get_lit_quote()
print(quote_data)
```